# socket write in for loop mixes string buffers

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, compiler-optimization, stringstream

I call a function multiple times using a for loop like this:

```
for ( int con=0; con < this->controller_info.size(); con++ ) {
  try {
    this->pi.home_axis( this->controller_info.at(con).addr );
  }
  catch( std::out_of_range &e ) { ... }
}
```

where the `home_axis()` function is defined as:

```
long ServoInterface::home_axis( int addr ) {
  std::stringstream cmd;
  if ( addr > 0 ) cmd << addr << " ";
  cmd << "FRF";
  cmd << "\n";
  int bytes=this->controller.Write( cmd.str() );
  return NO_ERROR;
}
```

and the `controller.Write()` function is just a wrapper for the standard `write(2)` which writes the characters in the string to a socket file descriptor.

You can see that each time `home_axis()` is called it should have its own, fresh, `std::stringstream cmd` buffer. But what is happening is that, *for the first time* the for loop executes, the host that is receiving the bytes written by home_axis, is receiving a single string, once:

```
1 FRF2 FRF
```

but if I print the bytes written then it prints 6, twice. So the writer is writing correctly, 6 bytes two different times, but the host is receiving it apparently as a single buffer.

If I execute that for loop again, then the host receives (properly),

```
1 FRF
```

and then

```
2 FRF
```

handling the two received buffers each as they come in.

How can the `std::stringstream cmd` buffers be getting mixed like this?

There are no threads involved here.

In an effort to pick this apart a bit, if I insert just 1µsec of delay in that for loop, i.e. `usleep(1);` then it works properly. Also, if I call the `home_axis()` function manually, but equally rapid succession, without using a for loop like this,

```
this->pi.home_axis( this->controller_info.at(0).addr );
this->pi.home_axis( this->controller_info.at(1).addr );
```

then that also works.

So I'm wondering if it's possible there is a compiler optimization going on?

Comment: It is possible the problem is with your receiver code, but it is not being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the compiler at all.

TCP is a byte stream.  It has no concept of message boundaries.  There is no 1:1 relationship between writes and reads.  You can write 2 messages of 6 bytes each, and the receiver may receive all 12 bytes at a time, or 1 byte and then 11 bytes, or any combination in between.  That is just the way TCP works.  By default, it breaks up data packets as it sees fit to optimize transmissions.

What is important is that TCP guarantees the bytes will be delivered (unless the connection is lost), and it will deliver the bytes in the same order that they are written.

As such, the sender must indicate in the data itself where each message begins and ends.  Either by sending a message's length before its content, or by separating each message with a unique delimiter (as you are).

On the receiving side, a single read may receive a partial message, or pieces of multiple messages, etc.  It is the receiver's responsibility to buffer incoming bytes and extract only complete messages from that buffer as needed, regardless of however many reads it takes to complete them.

As you are delimiting your messages with a trailing `\n`, the receiver should buffer all bytes and extract only messages that have received their `\n`, leaving any incomplete message at the end of the buffer for subsequent reads to finish.

This way, message boundaries are preserved and handled correctly.

Comment: I think roughly 100% of new TCP programmers have this misconception -- it's enough to make me wish that TCP had some built-in API to support for specifying/sending message-boundaries, if only so that we could tell new programmers to use that rather than having to roll their own buffering logic.  :/

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Unfortunately, TCP-based protocols vary widely in their formats (text messages vs binary messages? Leading lengths vs terminators? Have you seen how many different boundary formats HTTP uses inside *each* of its messages?). So, it is not really feasible to design a generic API to handle this automatically for everyone.  But, there are higher-level messaging libraries that do handle this, if you don't mind using their formats.

Comment: all valid questions... but since we're imagining, my thought was something like `tcp_begin_batch_marker(int fd)` and `tcp_end_batch_marker(int fd)` calls that the sender could bracket his series of zero or more `send()` calls with; the TCP layer would use those to generate out-of-band metadata to avoid marking the receiver's socket as ready-for-read until the end-batch-marker had been received, and the next `recv()` call would be guaranteed to return the entire batch.  (Yes, there would probably need to be some maximum batch size enforced to avoid excessive RAM usage on the receiving side)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You want [reliable UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol).

Comment: I was about to say 'but the receiver is getting "1 FRF2 FRF" -- with no \n between' when I went and looked at my receiver code. Sure enough, I'm re-using code there which strips the newline character.

Comment: @jxh throw in FIFO-ordering guarantees and large(ish) maximum-message sizes (e.g. megabytes) and I'm sold :)

Comment: As @RemyLebeau points out, I'm already sending a delimiter so I overloaded my Read() wrapper in the receiver code with a version that passes a delimiter and now my problem is solved. -- I totally overlooked what my receiver was doing when looking at this problem.